# Need help is defining an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $$A = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & {a-2b} \end{bmatrix} 
\mid
a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a^2 \ne 2ab
\right\}$$
where the group operation is matrix multiplication.

Let $$A'= \left\{(c,d) \mid c,d\in \mathbb{R}, c,d \ne 0\right\}$$ with group operation $(c_1,d_1)(c_2,d_2) =(c_1c_2,d_1d_2)$.

I need to prove that these are isomorphic, so i need to show that A is isomorphic to some group of permutations and A' is isomorphic to that same group and therefore A and A' are isomorphic. I am not sure how to find the isomorphism to a permutation group in either case so any guidance as to how I would go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you

Comment: I assume $A$ isn't that matrix, but it's supposed to be the group of all such matrices? Anyways, why bother with a permutation group? Just find the isomorphism directly. The condition of which pairs of parameters to exclude should be a *big* hint as to the correspondence between them. It might help to write the elements of $A$ as pairs $(a,b)$ rather than as matrices, and work out the group law in terms of that representation.

Comment: Why do you want to involve permutations???

Comment: I have reformatted the question for clarity, addressing in particular the doubts expressed by @Hurkyl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Find a direct isomorphism.
2. The *unit* of $A'$ is $(1,1)$, the unit of $A$ is with $a=1,\,b=0$, they must be mapped to each other.
3. Consider the following assignments $c:=a,\ d:=a-2b$, and its inverse: $a:=c,\ b:=\frac{a-d}2$.
4. $\pmatrix{a&b\\0&u}\cdot\pmatrix{x&y\\0&v}=\pmatrix{au&bu+cv\\0&cd}$, and in case $b=\displaystyle\frac{a-u}2$ and $y=\displaystyle\frac{x-v}2$, check that we also have $bu+cv=\displaystyle\frac{au-cd}2$.

Answer (score 3):

If you let $c=a-2b$, then you also have $b = \frac{a-c}{2}$, and so your group of matrices can be written as 
\begin{equation}
A=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a && \frac{a-c}{2} \\
0 && c
\end{pmatrix} | a,c\in \mathbb R, c\neq 0
\right\}.
\end{equation}
Note that the $c\neq 0$ condition follows $a^2 \neq 2ab$.

I think the isomorphism should be relatively obvious, but let me know if you can't see it.